# NullInjectorError: No provider for Firebase! for Ionic Framework

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic3

I was following https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm/
to integrate Firebase into my Ionic project. It was showing runtime error, not finding a Firebase provider.

Runtime error:

[image]

Comment: Did you install and import firebase in your app and page

Comment: I installed 
Cordova and Ionic Native plugins using :

$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/fcm

 . Inside app.component.ts I added

import { FCM } from '@ionic-native/fcm';

constructor(private fcm: FCM) {}

Answer (score 8):

This might be because you forgot to add it in your app module providers list.

Import it in your app.module.ts and add it to the providers list it should then work

```
import {FCM} from '@ionic-native/fcm'

@NgModule({
  ... 
  providers : [
    ... 
    FCM
  ]
})
```

Comment: @ionic-native/fcm , not found

Comment: use @ionic-native/fcm/ngx